# Abelian subgroup in an infinite non-abelian $3$-group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

> Does an infinite non-abelian $3$-group has an infinite abelian subgroup?

This result holds for $2$-groups, but I wonder whether this holds or not for $3$-groups.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $3$ were $>10^{75}$, a [Tarski Monster group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski_monster_group) would work as counterexample

Comment: I don't understand the context "3 were $> 10^{75}$". Can you explain a little bit.

Comment: Here i am interested with the prime $3$, not any ordinary prime.

Comment: What about $H\oplus\mathbb{Z}_3^\infty$ where $H$ is any infinite non-abelian 3-group?

Comment: @Boris Novikov: Is it not that $\mathbb{Z}_{3}^{\infty}$ is a direct product of $\mathbb{Z}_3$ infinite times? And thus it is an infinite abelian subgroup of the given group.

Comment: @deibor: Yes, it is.

Comment: @Boris Novikov: So you are giving an example of an  infinite non-abelian 3-group that has an infinite abelian subgroup.

Comment: @deibor: Sorry, I understood the question wrong.

Comment: Its alright and i appreciate for your help.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen those have been constructed for much lower bounds now (still not for $3$ though).

Comment: I don't thaink that a Tarski Monster exists for the prime 3, as every finitely generated 3-group is finite (Burnside).  So note that your 3-group is locally finite.

Comment: @Tobias Kildetoft: For the prime 3, there is no tarski Monster group. There is a result that says " Any finitely generated group of exponent 3 is finite".

Comment: @deibor Ahh, thank you. I had forgotten that result.

Comment: @Tobial Kildetoft. You are welcome.

Comment: I think the answer is affirmative, as I think there is a result stating that every locally finite, infinite group contains an infinite abelian group.  I not sure, I will confirme this later.

Comment: @Yassine Guerboussa: You are right. It is due to Phillip Hall and others. So the answer is yes then.

Comment: @deibor: My argument works for the exponent 3, I don't know what is the answer in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is affirmative if $G$ has exponent $3$.

Recall that a group $G$ is locally finite if every finite subset of $G$ generates a finite subgroup, that is if every finitely generated subgroup of $G$ is finite.  It follows from a well known result on Burnside Problem, that every 3-group is locally finite.

Now from a result of P. Hall, Kulatilaka and Kargapolov (which can be found in Robinson's book
"A course in the theory of groups", Section 14.3), one knows that every locally finite group which is infinite, contains an infinite abelian subgroup.

As, I think you have not imposed a condition on the exponent of $G$, I think there is $2$-generators groups of exponent $3^n$ with $n$ sufficiently large, in which every proper subgroup is cyclic, so do not contain infinite proper subgroup

Comment: For $3^n \geq 665$, and $d>1$, in the free Burnside group $B(d,3^n)$ (that is the quotient of the free group on $d$-generators by the subgroup generated by the $3^n$th powers), every finite or abelian subgroup is cyclic. (see, Adian S.I. The Burnside problem and identities in groups)